# Bulk Update the "My Social Accounts and Contacts" Preference for all Users

Tags: administration, user-record, user-management, user-admin

I'd like to enable Social Accounts and Contacts in our org, and then bulk update all Users to NOT have the "Use Social Accounts and Contacts" setting enabled.

This would allow me to then send out a notice that anyone who wanted to use the feature could turn it on. With our use of the platform, I find it likely that only a very small percentage of our users will benefit, most will find it an annoyance.

I've extracted the User table from a sandbox org (in which I have enabled Social Contacts), and can't find a field that corresponds to this setting. I've also looked to see if there is a separate object that handles this permission.

Comment: How many users are in your organisation?

Comment: A little over 150 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, there no permission for that.

Comment: Although this doesn't give me the answer that I want, it does help to verify that this isn't a plan I can move forward with. Instead, I will have to alert users to the change, and provide instructions on how they can disable Social Contacts. Because this deployment will be more intrusive, I will also be meeting with some of our stakeholders to make sure there is enough of a use case for Social Contacts.

Comment: I never seem to be able to comment on the main question, which is what I wanted to do. :-)